# Почему продолжает выполняться метод объекта после удаления его экземпляра?

Tags: python-3.x

есть класс Object, с методом func:

```
import time
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def func(self):
        x = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(self.name, x)
            x += 1
```

создаю экземпляр класса и вызываю метод func, потом удаляю экземпляр, но метод продолжает выполняться

```
obj = Object(name='myobj')
obj.func()
obj.delete()
```

Как остановить выполнение метода при удалении экземпляра?

Answer (score 1):

У вас не доходит выполнение до строчки с delete, т.к. выполняется бесконечный цикл в методе func.

```
obj.delete()
```

Кроме того, это не удаление, а попытка вызвать несуществующий метод delete. Для удаления используйте оператор del.

```
del obj
```

Comment: удаление имени из текущего пространства имён маловероятно что-то полезное для автора сделает (`del  имя` полезен, чтобы циклы в сборщике мусора разрывать). Стоит сказать, что Питон не обещает, что объект будет из памяти удалён даже если нет других ссылок на него -- реализация, в которой сборщик мусора выключен также остаётся Питоном.